# What is the regular expression to validate domains and subdomains using Regular Expression Pattern?

Tags: java, regex

I have a list of domains and sub-domains and i am checking if every single item from this list is a valid domain name (or sub-domain) like: **www.google.com** - **google.com** - **drive.google.com**.

This is my regular expression:  `^((?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,6}$`

And this is my code:

```java
// Validate Domains
    private boolean validateDomains (String domains) {
        String domainsList[] = domains.split("\\n");
        final Pattern domainPattern = Pattern.compile("^((?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,6}$");

        for (int i = 0; i < domainsList.length; i++) {
            if (!domainPattern.matcher(domainsList[i]).matches()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

This code never passes the tests!

Comment: Check this regex. https://regexr.com/3au3g

Comment: @Sambit i already did, but it doesn't work!

Comment: Based upon the example, is it not working ? I tried with your example and it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Or maybe, you would add more boundaries to your expression, similar to:

```
(?i)^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:[a-z0-9-]+\.){1,9}[a-z]{2,5}(?:\/.*)?$
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/J033Na/1/)

or

```
(?i)^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:[a-z0-9-]{1,20}\.){1,9}[a-z]{2,5}(?:\/.*)?$
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/Waivex/1/)

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class re{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        final String regex = "(?i)^(?:https?:\\/\\/)?(?:www\\.)?(?:[a-z0-9-]+\\.){1,9}[a-z]{2,5}(?:\\/.*)?$";
        final String string = "www.google.com\n"
             + "google.com\n"
             + "drive.google.com\n"
             + "http://www.google.com\n"
             + "http://google.com\n"
             + "http://drive.google.com\n"
             + "https://www.google.com\n"
             + "https://www.google.com\n"
             + "https://www.drive.google.com\n"
             + "https://www.google.com/some_other_things\n"
             + "https://www.google.com/\n"
             + "https://www.drive.google.com/\n"
             + "https://www.a.a.a.a.a.a.a.a.a.google.com/";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

#### Output

```
Full match: www.google.com
Full match: google.com
Full match: drive.google.com
Full match: http://www.google.com
Full match: http://google.com
Full match: http://drive.google.com
Full match: https://www.google.com
Full match: https://www.google.com
Full match: https://www.drive.google.com
Full match: https://www.google.com/some_other_things
Full match: https://www.google.com/
Full match: https://www.drive.google.com/
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/J033Na/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/J033Na/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have found the right Regular Expression for this code!
`^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$`
This RegEx worked very well for me.
Now this is my code:

```java
// Validate Domains
    private boolean validateDomains (String domains) {
        String domainsList[] = domains.split("\\n");
        final Pattern domainPattern = Pattern.compile("^(http:\\/\\/www\\.|https:\\/\\/www\\.|http:\\/\\/|https:\\/\\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\\-\\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\\/.*)?$");

        for (int i = 0; i < domainsList.length; i++) {
            if (!domainPattern.matcher(domainsList[i]).matches()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  private boolean validateDomains (String domains) {
        return Arrays.stream(domains.split("\\n")).allMatch(domain -> domain.matches("\"^((?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)\\\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,6}$\""));
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, while this might technically answer the question consider adding an explanation.

Comment: sorry Jhonny, i speak a poor english, can you explain more?

Comment: give an example of domain we will see for the regex